# Yii2 - rest - encrypt output for all actions

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2, output

I'm writing an `Yii restfull` application. I could manage the input by overwrite `ActiveController` and `init()` method. But I want to encrypt the output of all actions of all controllers and unfortunately I have no idea how can I do that...!

Can any one help me ...?

Answer (score 1):

You could use action events to modify data before or after executing controllers. Just override EVENT_AFTER_ACTION event, get the output generated and encrypt it with whatever algorithm you desire.

Then the output of all actions in the controller with be encrypted.

Here is a good reference for Yii2 events:

[Yii2 events documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-events.html#)

[Yii2 events API guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-event.html)

Comment: in `public function afterAction($action, $result){
        $result = parent::afterAction($action, $result);
        return $this->encrypt($result);
    }` method also `$result` is not in json mode and this is not the last step!

Comment: @MasoudNazari Read the documentation and API guide provided in the answer. Find the event that gets triggered on your use case, If you override that you'll get the result